# Universal Game Packs

Tags: playing-cards

I'd heard at one point that someone was working on a "Universal Game Pack" that provided the components necessary to play a large number of games, just as one can with a regular deck of cards.

For example, with a deck of cards numbered from 1 to 135, I can play war, No Thanks, Category 5, and others. With a regular deck plus four special cards, I can play Tichu. Throw in a bag of universal tokens and I can play a bunch of other games.

Has anybody heard of a universal game pack like this?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the Rainbow Deck:

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/59655/rainbow-deck

Decks that it can be mapped into:

- Sequence of numbers of 0 to 119
- Letters with values similar to the game system Letter Head and similar games
- 12 suits (colour/number) x 1-13 values
- 6 suits (icon) x 1-23 values (2x10+3)
- 6 suits (icon) x 2 copies of 1-13 values
- 12 suits (colour/number) x 2 copies of 1-6 dice values
- 6 suits (icon) x 4 copies of 1-6 dice values
- 6 suits (icon) x 26 letter cards
- n * 26 letter cards + rare letter cards
- 1 copy x value 1,..., 12 copies x value 12(Q), 13 copies x value 13(K+joker)
- Double-Nine domino set x 2 copies

The page on BoardGameGeek has downloads of a pdf you can print, info on where to buy one and a file listing the games that can be played with it. I'm pretty sure it covers most of what you would want.

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1147935/where-get-rainbow-deck